# Testing Firefox WebExtensions on Android

Tags: android, firefox-addon-webextensions

i'm trying to test a web extension for firefox android but i don't know how to install it. I tried making the package using web-ext build.

Comment: Please ask an actual question, rather than just stating your lack of knowledge.

Comment: Related: [Installing unsigned XPIs in Firefox for Android version 42 or newer](//stackoverflow.com/q/36049137)

Comment: Related but not useful, since it's no legacy XPI, but a new WebExtension

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same `web-ext run` to run your extension on your android device by specifying target device details.

Example: `web-ext run --target=firefox-android --android-device XXXXYYYYZZZZ`

Where `XXXXYYYYZZZZ` is the device id that can be obtained by `adb devices` command.